# What do these git commands exactly do?

Tags: git, github, mozilla

I am contributing to an open source project and I understand that the following is the standard for git workflow. I need a clear understanding. This is taken from the documentation:

1. Install our development environment
2. Set up mozilla remote (`$ git remote add mozilla git://github.com/mozilla/kuma.git`)
3. Create a branch for a bug (`$ git checkout -b new-issue-888888`)
   Develop on bug branch.

[Time passes, the `mozilla/kuma` repository accumulates new commits]

4. Commit changes to bug branch (`$ git add . ; git commit -m 'fix bug 888888 - commit message'`)
5. Fetch mozilla (`$ git fetch mozilla`)
6. Update local master (`$ git checkout master; git pull mozilla master`)

Repeat steps 4-7 till dev is complete

7. Rebase issue branch (`$ git checkout new-issue-888888; git rebase master`)
8. Push branch to GitHub (`$ git push origin new-issue-888888`)
9. Issue pull request (Click Pull Request button)

I have understood the most part though. From #1, I have forked kuma and cloned it to my local machine. This sets up a remote *origin* back to from where I cloned. #2- Original repo has been added as *mozilla* remote. Now I have 2 remotes; *origin* and *mozilla*. #3- checkout a branch named `new-issue-888888`. By the time, the *mozilla* accumulates new commits. #4, changes committed to *origin*. Not quite clear from #5 onwards. No idea about rebase.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Which bits didn't you understand? Did you try doing it and observe what changed? Which step was confusing? Did something actually fail? If so, what?

Comment: I am really curious about this. Why doing #5 if the `git pull mozilla master` in #6 will also do a  `fetch` ?

Comment: Possibly just so people can distinguish between fetch and merge failures? Agree it would be simpler to just pull, or clearer to fetch+merge explicitly though.

Comment: Yes I read the docs. Didn't quite understand how rebase works. Also, After a checkout a feature branch, this is what I think I'd do. Edit a file with my changes, save and commit. Is this the right method? What is meant by "submit a patch" Does it mean the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5. Fetch mozilla (`$ git fetch mozilla`)
   This downloads any changes that were made on the original Mozilla remote, but doesn't change your working directory. It is preparation for below.
6. Update local master (`$ git checkout master; git pull mozilla master`)
   This switches to the `master` branch and updates it with the commits of `mozilla/master`. Now your master is in sync with the remote one.
7. Rebase issue branch (`$ git checkout new-issue-888888; git rebase master`)
   This integrates the changes that have happened on `master` (the continued development of Mozilla since you started on your patch) into your feature branch. This is required so your branch will be a conflict-less merge.
8. Push branch to GitHub (`$ git push origin new-issue-888888`)
   Now you push your feature to your fork of the original repo on github, so you can send a PR from the UI.
9. Issue pull request (Click Pull Request button)
   Finally send the pull request out to the main repo. If you were too slow with 7-9 the master branch could have moved on. In that case gitbub will inform you that there is a merge conflict, you will need to restart from step 5.

Comment: Isn't the #5 step unnecessary?

Comment: @KeillRandor that kind of threw me off too, but as Useless said above, it's probably to prevent pull from erroring halfway through.

Comment: Had that doubt! The difference between git fetch mozilla and git pull mozilla master. Both of them updates with commits of mozilla/master? However, its clear now. Thanks!

Comment: Do people usually edit the existing file and commit. Or copy the file, make changes to the duplicate, and create a patch?

Comment: @abhidoeslinux the point of a VCS is that you can't break history. Making a copy only makes things more complicated, and applying a patch with wrong filenames screws with everything. Just edit the file, if you screw up, you can always revert to the previous state.

Comment: @abhidoeslinux also `git fetch` does not change your master branch, you can think of it kind of as "caching" of the remote branch. Without `git pull` the changes won't appear in your local master.